# Why do I need 3 `for`s to use a double-for loop generator?

Tags: python

For a puzzle program, I needed to write a double-loop where I break out of the middle loop, and it required a weird break/else/continue/break construction that didn't feel right.

User @AdamSmith showed me a method to get around this, but I can't understand why replacing the first loop requires 3-for statements to eliminate a double-loop.

Is it possible to replace Original version only using 2 `for` keywords? Seeing 3 to me signals that it's a triple loop construct (which I guess it kind of is, but one of those loops is supposed to be abstracted away under `pandigitals()`).

```
import itertools
import Util

def pandigitals(i):
    as_string = ''.join( str(k) for k in range (i, 0, -1))

    return (itertools.permutations(as_string))

# Original version
for i in range (9, 0, -1):
    for j in pandigitals(i):
        d = int(''.join(j))

        if Util.is_prime(d):
            print (d)
            break
    else:
        continue # Gross
    break

# Get rid of the ugly break
for d in (int(''.join(j)) for i in range(9, 0, -1) for j in pandigitals(i)) :
    if Util.is_prime(d):
        print(d)
        break

# What I expected to work (doesn't)
'''
for j in pandigitals(i) for i in range(9, 0, -1):
    d = int(''.join(j))

    if Util.is_prime(d):
        print (d)
        break
'''
```

Util.py:

```
def is_prime(i):
    if i % 2 == 0: return i == 2

    for j in range (3, int(sqrt(i) + 1), 2):
        if i % j == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

*Add:*
It just came up again and my brain exploded a little...

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for word in (x for row in reader for x in row):
```

Is there really no better way to one-liner a for loop?

Comment: In this particular example the best way to break out of two nested loops would be to put those loops into a function and change the inner break to a return statement.

Comment: Also, your second example isn't as nested as you think.  The outer for-loop iterates concurrently with the for-loops in the generator expression.  So it doesn't add an extra level of nesting (the performance is still quadratic).

Comment: Just a hint: you can use the [divisibility rule for 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_3_or_9) to check if all numbers of one permutation are divisible by 3, as the sum of digits will be the same for all permutations. That way you can immediately tell that none of the results of `pandigitals(i)` with an i of 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, and 9 can be prime.

Comment: @mata Thanks but I'm really just trying to understand the double-for loop generators here.

Comment: This appears to be a question about a programming problem that you have _a_ solution for, but that you think could be improved. Have you considered asking on codereview.stackexchange.com?